# Django query by separate date and time fields (how to perform conditional order_by)

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a `Meeting` model. It has a separate date and time field, the reason why it is not a single datetime field is that the time is allowed to be null.
If I used a single `datetime` field and set the hours/minutes to `00:00` if no time is given, then I can't distinguish that from a meeting set at `00:00`. And some unusual sentinel value like `13:37:42` as no meeting is a weird hack.

Here's the model:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    meeting_date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    meeting_time = models.TimeField(db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now the problem comes in to filter by a given date/time.

So I think the solution is to filter by date, then order by the time. E.g. to get the latest meeting that is before now:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
prev_meeting = (
    Meeting.objects.filter(meeting_date__lte=now.date())
    .order_by('-meeting_date', f'meeting_time <= {now.time()}', '-meeting_time')
    .first()
)
```

The  `f'meeting_time <= {now.time()}'` is the part I don't know how to do with the django ORM, but I know how to do with SQL. the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) do not mention conditional ordering.

Comment: Why not to include `meeting_time__lte=now.time()` into filter?

Comment: @Ersain Because if the previous meeting was the day before at a later time than now, it will be filtered out, but should not be.

Comment: I think instead of showing codes, you should give date-time examples and what your goal is. Like, give examples of date times and let us know what you want to get in different scenarios. I think I will be able to solve the issue then. I have worked with meeting management apps before but never used Date & Time in 2 different columns. We might be able to solve your problem in a different way if you can explain it properly

Comment: @ShahriarRahmanZahin Which part is unclear about how to sort by separate date/time fields, I will ammend the post accordingly.

Comment: "E.g. to get the latest meeting that is before now" There are some terms you have used That I did not get. Could you please just give date-related examples that show before and after query results which you are expecting?

Comment: @ShahriarRahmanZahin If you read the Django Docss, they use the terms `earliest` and `latest`, which mean exactly what they mean. `now` means the current date time at this point in time, also used in Django/Python documentation. But don't worry, I found a solution I posted below, thanks.

Comment: You didn't highlight the "now" as code, I thought you are just trying to explain it lol. BTW thanks for mentioning django docs even though it was unnecessary. Glad that you figured it out.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution I came up with is to use a single `datetime` field to store the date/time, and then instead of a sentinel time value, I have an additional boolean value storing whether the time was set or not. If the time was not set, then then datetime time is `00:00` and the `time_was_set` field is set to `False`.